# How do I allow JavaScript execCommand("paste") to work in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, clipboard

When the user clicks on a specific button on my screen I want to paste the content of the clipboard into a specific text field.

I currently use the code:

```
pasteSelectedTextFromClipboard() {
    const input = this.$refs.input as any
    input.focus()
    document.execCommand("paste")
}
```

When I Google I find that in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) it's necessary to set `user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "allowclipboard");` to allow this functionality to work. What do I have to do to get it to work in Electron?

Answer (score 0):

Electron exposes very good [API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard#clipboard) for all operations with the clipboard

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`clipboard.readText()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard#clipboardreadtexttype) from the Electron clipboard API for this:

```js
const { clipboard } = require("electron")

const input = document.getElementById("textbox")
input.value = clipboard.readText()
```

An added advantage: you will no longer need to focus the input element, as you are programmatically setting its value.

Note that this will replace all of the input's current text by what is in the clipboard.